# Create a layout in XML and use it several times

Tags: android

I´d like to design a layout in XML and want to duplicate it dynamicly, depence on the size of a list. It has to be done in a fragment. Unfortunally I cannot find how to do it in fragments.

This ist the idea of the XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
   >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/complete_map_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ICH bin die MAP!! Ich möchte ein Bild werden"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <!-- Erstellung einzelner Räume -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/roomRow">

        <!-- Bezeichnung Raum -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/roomNameOne"
            android:background="#ff0000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/roomName"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:rotation="-90"
                android:text="PLATZHALTER"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Inhalt Raum -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/WeaponNameOne">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/testWeapon"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="WAFFE"
                android:background="#00ff00"/>
        </LinearLayout>



        <!-- Inhalt Raum2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/weaponNameTwo"
            android:background="#0000ff">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/testWeapon2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="WAFFE"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Bezeichnung Raum2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:id="@+id/roomNameTwo"
            android:background="#ff0000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/roomName2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="PLATZHALTER"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the java-code:

```
public class MapOverview extends Fragment {
Bundle extras;
View fragLayoutV;
Game game;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragLayoutV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);
    extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    game = (Game) extras.get("GAME");
    return fragLayoutV;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)fragLayoutV.findViewById(R.id.complete_map_layout);
    //LinearLayout roomInflator = (LinearLayout)frame.findViewById(R.id.roomRow);

    Log.e("RAUM", game.getRooms().get(0).getName());
    for(Room r:game.getRooms()){
        frame.addView((LinearLayout)frame.findViewById(R.id.roomRow));
    }

}
```

}

Of course I get an error by doing this. Can anybody help?

The aim is to have a picture like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DS73.png

Don´t matter about the colors ^^

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i cannot add more childs than one to the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-inflate your layout every time you want to add it. You can not add the same `View` multiple times.

Try something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());

for (Room r : game.getRooms()) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_duplicate_layout, frame, false);
    // Do whatever you want with view

    frame.addView(view);
}
```

Where `R.layout.your_duplicate_layout` correspond to your current layout with id=roomRow.

Comment: damed... Enter sends the text...
is there a alternative for "getContext()" ?
Because the API has to be 23 for that and Im trying to write it for 15

Comment: If you are using the support library, `getContext()` should work. Otherwise, you can use `getActivity()`.